# API return type -- Force a smart pointer onto the user?

Tags: c++, pointers

Suppose I have an API-border function that creates and returns an object:

```
<?> createOneObject();
```

What would be the best way to return the object to the caller?

- Return the raw `MyObject*` and let the caller handle the pointer herself
- Return `std::shared_ptr<MyObject>`
- Something else?

Comment: Depends on the situation. Generally I'd say returning a `std::unique_ptr` is best, as the user can always release the pointer or convert it to a `std::shared_ptr` if needed. An even better option is to avoid dynamic allocation if you don't need it. If you post a concrete example we can give concrete advice; this is currently a bit broad.

Comment: Neither. Return a `unique_ptr`. Then the user can at her discretion construct a shared pointer from it or call `release()`.

Comment: I've made a drastic edit to your question, in the hope of making it more clear and to-the-point. Do feel free to rollback if you don't like my version :)

Comment: If the object is small or movable I would return it by value. Otherwise unique_ptr is usually the right choice.

Comment: You might want to read ["Top 10 dumb mistakes to avoid with C++ 11 smart pointers"](http://www.acodersjourney.com/2016/05/top-10-dumb-mistakes-avoid-c-11-smart-pointers/), especially check out the item in the list.

Comment: Thank you so far.

To be a bit more concrete: I have a player class that just stores an id and just offers lots of methods. In this case you would prefer to return by value?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Depends.

In general, returning a raw pointer is bad, because the type itself does not communicate ownership. Should the user delete the pointer? If yes, then how? If not, then when does the library do it? How does the user know if the pointer is still valid? Those things have to be documented, and lazy programmers might skip reading the docs. But, if your API must be callable from C or other languages, then a raw pointer may be the only option.

Shared pointer might be useful in special cases, but they do have overhead. If you don't need *shared* ownership, then use of a shared pointer may be overkill.

Unique pointer is what I would use unless there is specific reason to use something else.

Although, that assumes that a pointer should be returned in the first place. Another great option could be to return an object.

> To be a bit more concrete: I have a player class that just stores an id and just offers lots of methods. In this case you would prefer to return by value?

Most definitely.

Comment: Should I mark this as the answer? The comments answered my question too. Thanks anyway!

Comment: @stulleman You should mark the *answer* that you find most helpful. Comments don't count as answers and cannot be "accepted" (the commenters are free to write an answer, but chose to write a comment instead, possibly because they were too busy to write a detailed one).

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options (without any nasty drawbacks):

**C Style**

Have a matching `void destroyOneObject(MyObject* object);` that cleans up the resource. This is the proper choice when destroying the object isn't as simple as deleting it (e.g. needs to be unregistered at some manager class).

**Smart pointer**

When all that needs to happen is to delete the object, return a `std::unique_ptr<MyObject>`. This uses RAII to clean up the object, and fits modern C++ a lot better.

**The bad solutions**

Don't return a raw pointer and call delete on it. You cannot guarantee that the delete matches the new that was used to create the object. It also doesn't communicate very well if you are supposed to delete it in the first place.

Don't use shared pointers. They are complete overkill in almost any situation, and are usually the result of a lack of understanding of an application's structure.

Comment: I think 'They are complete overkill in almost any situaton' is way to broad. shared_ptr is very useful, but sometimes unique_ptr is a better choice, and allows clearer APIs to be created.

Comment: Note that you can attach a custom deleter to a `std::unique_ptr`.

Comment: @ErikAlapää From writing GUI applications to low level hardware controllers, I've never been in a situation where `std::shared_ptr` was the best solution. If anything it is the laziest solution.

Comment: @RickdeWater They are both in the standard because both are useful. shared_ptr is for shared ownership, while unique_ptr is for exclusive ownership. But application design requires careful thought, e.g. to not get loops of shared_ptr between layers in the application.